# Perform ops class from console

Tags: python, add-on, command-line

When loading any file, the [`sun_position` add-on/plug-in](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Sun_Position), although enabled in User Preferences, is disabled in its panel. When trying to dynamically render a scene, using a python file:

```
blender -b blenderfile.blend -P pythonfile.py -o //outputfile_ -E CYCLES -F PNG -x 1 -f 1
```

the `sun_position` plugin is not enabled.

I've tried to invoke the function `bpy.ops.world.sunpos_controller()` from `pythonfile.py`, but to no avail. I've also tried to change the `sun_position` configuration files to be enabled by default, but I couldn't manage to get that to work either.

Does anyone have an idea on how to render a scene from a terminal with `sun_position` enabled?

Comment: Have you tried adding --addons? You can use this followed by a comma separated list of addons. Use in place of your Python script.

Comment: @ShadyPuck Doesn't seem to do anything. I'm pretty sure the `sun_position` add-on is enabled within Blender's settings, just not on the module itself.